# Is it fine if i simply just add more RAM?

Tags: memory

I have Crucial 8GB 2133MHZ DDR4 Desktop Memory inside my computer currently, and want to buy a 16GB kit, should I just add the new memory to the computer? It has 4 DIMM Slots, this is my computer stats:

[image]

The RAM I want to buy is the same as the RAM that's already in.

Would it be compatible to just add 2 more sticks?

Just want to know if its fine if I just install the 16GB Kit without changing anything, also is there a specific way it should be installed? Sorry for the stupid question, just always scared of buying expensive products

Comment: "Would it be compatible to just add 2 more sticks? " - If it will be compatible will be determine by the motherboard specifications.  Read the motherboard specifications to determine if it supports running 32GB of memory in a 4x8 GB configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound - Doesn't the questioner want to use 3x8GB? That's how I read the question.

Comment: Sometimes you don't need to read the Motherboard specs to know that an Intel i7 6700 is a Dual Channel CPU. The person who installed a single module in your PC made a huge mistake. If I were you I'd get an identical ram module to the one you already have and add it to the correct slot (that's when you have to check the mobo specs).

Comment: If you already have 1 and you want to add 2 others. yes it will work and I assume you have the same brand and model for the ram of course. Is it the best way to do it ? Probably not because of the dual channel issue. You should go with 3 other sticks if you want to add more than 2 in this case. Also...stupid question but why do you need more than 8gb ?

Comment: I would recommend just adding a single 8GB module if bang for your buck is the goal and 24GB is not required;  this would put you in dual channel mode and double you memory.  16GB would rarely get "used up" by even a power user.  Although the additional caching allowed from the additional RAM can speed thing up apparently your SSD should be fast enough to not notice much of a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your motherboard info ---> [1](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-B150M-D3H-rev-10#ov)

For memory support list ---> [2](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-B150M-D3H-rev-10#support-doc)

You can buy them, it is fine, but 3 of them will not be dual channel. to have dual channel, fill both black or both grey, or buy additional 3 pieces and all slot filled. or, just buy 1 8GB RAM and fill either black / grey, depends on where the other is.

Comment: If its not dual channel and I add 2 so there will be 3 in total, will it decrease the speed? or whats the big problem with not having it in a dual channel?

Comment: The big problem is performance. Here is the link for further study

https://beebom.com/single-channel-vs-dual-channel-memory/

Comment: So if i have the opportunity to buy 2 for the price of one, i should only use one? I currently have only 1 Stick and its running just fine

Comment: for gaming ? use only 1

Comment: for others, use both

Comment: Unrelated question, if I were to have 4 8GB sticks in total, would it also decrease performance or still work as dual?

Comment: if you have 4 8GB: you will have the best of both world... extra memory and all dual. btw: please mark as answers so i can collect points. thanks